# Casting a tab bar controller's navigation controller's visible view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a tab bar with 5 tabs, in the first tab, the first view controller is called the `WelcomeViewController`. I'm trying to grab the `visibleViewContoller` and cast it into a `WelcomeViewController`, which is a subclass of `UIViewController`

```
UINavigationController *navCon = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[0];
WelcomeViewController *wc = [navCon visibleViewController];
wc.referrer = params[key];
```

Line 2 above gives me the following error:

> Incompatible pointer types initializing 'WelcomeViewController *' with an expression of type 'UIViewController * _Nullable'

How can I cast this so I can access and set its sub-properties like `referrer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a cast:

```
UINavigationController *navCon = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[0];
WelcomeViewController *wc = (WelcomeViewController *)[navCon visibleViewController];
wc.referrer = params[key];
```